# Return result of CASE with Posgres SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, hasura

I am trying to write a simple SQL function that will be used as a computed field in Hasura.io platform.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calling_mode(calling_row calling, hasura_session json)
RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN calling_row.seekerUserId = hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-user-id' THEN 'seeker'
    WHEN calling_row.partnerUserId = hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-user-id' THEN 'partner'
    ELSE 'none'
  END
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

This gives me an error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "calling_row"`.

I tried looking through several docs, but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that causes upper case letters, so if your original column name is `seekerUserId`, then into your function postgres converts it as `seekeruserid`, and that column is not found.

Try column names into double quotes, like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calling_mode(calling_row calling, hasura_session json)
RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN calling_row."seekerUserId" = hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-user-id' THEN 'seeker'
    WHEN calling_row."partnerUserId" = hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-user-id' THEN 'partner'
    ELSE 'none'
  END
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```